# Difference between the following hexcode show in the following Images

Tags: node.js, audio, binary, hex, iso

I'm facing a problem with playing audio in node.js() [Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66713540/audio-streaming-in-node-js-using-blob-http-the-same-way-as-natural-reader-does) and when i try to decode the file i got the following hexcode
Can anyone tell me the difference between the following hexcode shown in the following two images

[Hexcode of audio 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFMZj.png)

[Hexcode of audio 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV32b.png)

Comment: get the basics down pat then you weaponize yourself to solve questions like this independent of waiting for answers here ... write some code to iterate across a loop to generate a series of points on a sine curve ... plot that curve of points ... save those points to a WAV file ... write new code to read that WAV file and plot the points ... confirm both plots match ... this will expose you to the challenges of endianness and notion of storing and retrieving a 16 bit integer as two bytes ...  once you do all of these nuggets you will be well on your way to becoming fluent in digital audio

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but the problem is with the format, if instead of audio i try to send png image it gives me the same format. Please have look at the problem mentioned above (Problem link), i am struck in this for several days.